# Google Charts - Failing to render a Row

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have the below script. It is not rendering the 2006 data. Is there a problem with my script? (Data: UN's Millenium Development Goals, not all values have data)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });


google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Afghanistan');
    data.addColumn('number', 'India');

    data.addRow(["1993", null, 61.9]);
    data.addRow(["1999", null, 65.1]);
    data.addRow(["2000", 36.9, 61.8]);
    data.addRow(["2003", 16.1, null]);
    data.addRow(["2006", null, 74.2]);

    new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).draw(data, {
        curveType: "function"
 , width: 768, height: 908

 , title: 'Target 5.B: Achieve, by 2015, universal access to reproductive health. Antenatal care coverage, at least 1 visit.'
 , vAxis: { title: 'Percent' }

    });

}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id='chart_div'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AreaChart` appears not to draw anything if a data point doesn't have any values in the  data points next to it. With nulls (or the edge of the graph) on both sides of any data point, the area would be of width 0. I'd say this is a bug with the chart API (it should really draw an area of width 1 in this case), which you may want to file [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list).

In the meantime, you may want to use a different chart type. Would a scatter plot be appropriate? It would have the advantage of not showing a potentially misleading line between data points. For example, in the current plot the plotted line may not match the real shape of the data, since your data is sparse. Say there was a spike and then a drop in the blue data between 2001 and 2003- the area chart type appears to tell a different story (a straight slope), while a scatter plot would not tell any false stories between the data you do have.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a stacked area chart, which will show all the data points similar to a column chart.